# Change color conditionally Css

Tags: css

I'm using a third party component on my page, It has a class `dialog_RechatDialog0D55B000000P6Mv` where the Id changes for each post. how do I change color is `css` if the class contains `"dialog_RechatDialog"`, is that possible? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: No idea why the downvote (maybe for lack of research) but you can use attribute selectors (contains or starts with based on your needs).

Comment: Probably the downvote because for questions like that it's important to put a Fiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, assuming your dom element is a div .

```
div[class^='dialog_RechatDialog'] {
    color: yellow;  
}
```

All (div) with a class that starts (^) with string "diablo_RechatDialog"